# How to get a limited results back from a list with information from another table

Tags: sql, dataframe

Create SQL Query that returns the **even id, business id, user id,** and **transaction ID**

There is a couple of requirements for this question:

- limit the number of results by the amount listed in Table 1's '# of results allowed' column
- if there is more than one instance of a match grab the lower user id first

Table one:

| event_ID | Business ID | #_of_results_allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 1 |
| 101 | 201 | 2 |
| 102 | 202 | 4 |
| 103 | 203 | 0 |

Table two:

| date_ID | event_id | user_id | transaction_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D12 | 100 | 300 | zx1 |
| D13 | 100 | 301 | zx2 |
| D14 | 100 | 302 | zx3 |
| D15 | 101 | 303 | zx4 |
| D16 | 102 | 333 | zx5 |
| D17 | 102 | 333 | zx6 |
| D18 | 102 | 302 | zx7 |
| D19 | 102 | 304 | zx8 |
| D20 | 102 | 333 | zx9 |
| D21 | 102 | 302 | zx10 |
| D22 | 103 | 304 | zx11 |

What ive tried was:

```
Select t1.event_id, t1.business_id, t2.transaction_id, row_number() over(partition by t1.event_id order by t2.user_id) as row_number
From tableone t1
Join tabletwo t2 on t1.event_id = t2.event_id
Qualify row_number <= t1.#_of_results_allowed
```

but this did not help me with the second part and did not limit or order the user ID

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting platform-specific tags.  Please go ahead and (re)add the tag specific to the platform you're working with.

Comment: I've added on what I've worked on and what issues I'm still running across

Comment: @Sinnclaire tag your database

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select t1.event_id, t1.business_id, t2.user_id, t2.transaction_id 
from table1 t1
join (
    select * , row_number() over (partition by event_id order by user_id) rn 
    from table2
) t2 on t1.event_id = t2.event_id and t2.rn <= _of_results_allowed
```